# Layout-параметры для FrameLayout и VideoView для корректного отображения видеороликов

Tags: android, android-layout, videoview

Перерыл весь google, есть решения, но, или лыжи не едут, или я не догоняю - моя проблема не решается.
В приложении есть splash_screen_activity, в нем планируется проигрывать рекламные видеоролики или статичные картинки.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/lingua_plus_banner"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="LinguaPlus"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/adVideo"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_closead"
        android:tint="@color/accent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_margin="12dip"
        android:onClick="skip"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Подскажите, какие layout параметры нужно использовать для FrameLayout и VideoView для корректного масштабирования видеороликов, в ландшафтной и портретной ориентации? Какие пропорции должны быть у видеороликов? Разрешение? Что нужно сделать, чтобы видеоролики не отображались вот так - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD

Так выглядит на экране видео после выставления атрибутов match_parent у FrameLayout. Также оно выглядит при такой разметке:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/adVideo"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Атрибут `match_parent`?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, посмотрите результат

Answer (score 0):

Все решило layout_gravity="center"

```
<FrameLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
```